# How to compare the URL with pathVariable in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am keeping `/{id}/request` in the property file, and I will get `/3210/request` as a string value from the request. Could you please help to achieve this?

I have tried the below pattern match, and it's working fine, but I want to know if there is any other better way to achieve this.

```
boolean regex="/1234/request".matches("/\\d{4,5}/request");
```

Comment: The regex itself is fine. I'd expect it to be in a Spring annotation in a Controller endpoint, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to compare the URL with pathVariable in Java (with Regex) ?

One practice is to use combination of `Matcher.find()` and `Matcher.group()`, when you perform a match on a string using a regular expression pattern and a `Matcher` object, the `group()` method returns the substring that was matched by the entire pattern, as an instance i'm interested in `request` (note that not `/request`)

```
String url = "https://ireallydontcare.com/request";
String pathVariable = "request";
String regex = "^https:\\/\\/ireallydontcare\\.com\\/(.*)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
return matcher.find() && matcher.group(1).equals(pathVariable)
```

Also the `@RequestMapping` can include regular expressions to match specific URL patterns.

```
@GetMapping("/{key:\\d(4,5)}/request")
public String getUserById(@PathVariable("key") String key) {
    ...
}
```